# How to buy Ethereum in USA as a non-US citizen?

Tags: ether

I am a non-US citizen studying in USA. I have tried to create a coinbase and a gemini account but it has been stuck in account verification for the last 2 weeks with no hope in sight.

I have a US bank account and would like to buy some ether from it. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be bouncing through Bitcoin to do so. Using [LocalBitcoins.com](https://localbitcoins.com/), find someone near you willing to sell you bitcoins for USD cash.

Once you have bitcoins, transfer those to your Gemini account and swap them for Ether. Then you can transfer your Ether out without having a verified account, since from Gemini's perspective you didn't do anything in USD (which is the regulated currency).